# Missing md2 partition in raid

Tags: data-recovery, raid

today I restarted my machine and it is not booting, so I launched a recovery image and ran `lsblk` and this is the output:

```bsh
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0     3G  1 loop
nvme1n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1 259:16   0    32G  0 part
├─nvme1n1p2 259:17   0   512M  0 part
└─nvme1n1p3 259:18   0 444.4G  0 part
nvme0n1     259:4    0 476.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:5    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1
├─nvme0n1p2 259:6    0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0   511M  0 raid1
└─nvme0n1p3 259:7    0 444.4G  0 part
nvme2n1     259:8    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme2n1p1 259:9    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1
├─nvme2n1p2 259:10   0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0   511M  0 raid1
└─nvme2n1p3 259:11   0 444.4G  0 part
nvme3n1     259:12   0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme3n1p1 259:13   0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1
├─nvme3n1p2 259:14   0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0   511M  0 raid1
└─nvme3n1p3 259:15   0 444.4G  0 part
```

In documents it says you can mount `md2` and recovery files etc. but it looks like the data partition is missing, what should I do? Can I mount the data partition in any way? What happened to my data partition?

**EDIT**
`cat /proc/mdstat` output:

```bsh
root@rescue / # cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[0] nvme3n1p2[3] nvme2n1p2[2]
      523264 blocks super 1.2 [4/3] [U_UU]

md0 : active raid1 nvme0n1p1[0] nvme3n1p1[3] nvme2n1p1[2]
      33520640 blocks super 1.2 [4/3] [U_UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

The `mdadm.conf` is as follows:

```bsh
root@rescue / # cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
# mdadm.conf
#
# !NB! Run update-initramfs -u after updating this file.
# !NB! This will ensure that initramfs has an uptodate copy.
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=ac0c4fe3:e447da2e:c329a42e:39201624 name=rescue:0
ARRAY /dev/md/1  metadata=1.2 UUID=adcd0f2c:276ba739:39bc8438:ed925281 name=rescue:1
ARRAY /dev/md/2  metadata=1.2 UUID=4dc7bc3a:190cd6fc:abfac538:b9bd2481 name=rescue:2

# This configuration was auto-generated on Mon, 14 Mar 2022 21:14:40 +0100 by mkconf
```

Also the machine is hosted in cloud, I only have access to rescue image.

**EDIT**

Here is info about `md0` and `md1`:

```
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Fri May 21 14:18:17 2021
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 33520640 (31.97 GiB 34.33 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 33520640 (31.97 GiB 34.33 GB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Mon Mar 14 18:23:49 2022
             State : clean, degraded
    Active Devices : 3
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : rescue:0  (local to host rescue)
              UUID : ac0c4fe3:e447da2e:c329a42e:39201624
            Events : 33664

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        5        0      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1p1
       -       0        0        1      removed
       2     259        9        2      active sync   /dev/nvme2n1p1
       3     259       13        3      active sync   /dev/nvme3n1p1
```

```
/dev/md1:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Fri May 21 14:18:17 2021
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 523264 (511.00 MiB 535.82 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 523264 (511.00 MiB 535.82 MB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Mon Mar 14 21:18:38 2022
             State : clean, degraded
    Active Devices : 3
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : rescue:1  (local to host rescue)
              UUID : adcd0f2c:276ba739:39bc8438:ed925281
            Events : 337

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        6        0      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1p2
       -       0        0        1      removed
       2     259       10        2      active sync   /dev/nvme2n1p2
       3     259       14        3      active sync   /dev/nvme3n1p2
```

**EDIT**
The resync is done at this point and I can access it via `mount /dev/md2 /mnt`.

```
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md2 : active raid6 nvme0n1p3[0] nvme3n1p3[3] nvme2n1p3[2]
      931788800 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [U_UU]
      bitmap: 4/4 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[0] nvme3n1p2[3] nvme2n1p2[2]
      523264 blocks super 1.2 [4/3] [U_UU]

md0 : active raid1 nvme0n1p1[0] nvme3n1p1[3] nvme2n1p1[2]
      33520640 blocks super 1.2 [4/3] [U_UU]
```

Comment: What are the expected raid configurations ? What raid fails to mount ? What error  do you get ? Any other information that can cast light on where the problem is ?

Comment: Honestly, I am not even sure what is going on, the system just straight up does not boot and it is a cloud hosting service so I do not have much control on it. All I have is this rescue system that runs from pxe boot. Not sure which configuration I went with raid too... I appreciate if you can tell me in any way I can add more information to the post, like what command outputs do you need?

Comment: My only suspect is that, there is about 15 docker containers that starts at boot, they may lock up the system but there is one another server with the same specs and it runs well with 30+.

Comment: Can you run `sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0` and `sudo mdadm -D /dev/md1` so we can see how the RAID 1 is configured for the 4 drives it shows.  RAID 1 is a mirror, but you are showing 2 different sized drives and not 1, so I am scratching my head trying to figure out how it is configured.

Comment: It says 2x1tb nvme ssds in it but looks like there is 4 of them? Maybe they include the mirroring feature by default, So umm, I didn't have much time and ran `mdadm --assemble --scan --force`, not sure if I should have done that but, md2 is recognized and it is re-syncing.

Comment: I also added the command outputs to the question.

Comment: You are showing 2x500GB and 2x1TB.  That is what is throwing me off.  Hard to see what exactly the mirror is there.  But, you can watch the `watch -n 1 cat /proc/mdstat` to watch the progress of the md2 rebuild.

Comment: It is still resyncing and 25 minutes left. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Also when I started resyncing, it stated this thing `mdadm: /dev/md2 has been started with 3 drives (out of 4).`. Maybe one of them is corrupted?

Comment: Okay the resync is done and I can access the drive, but is there anything I need to do in order the machine to boot, or it is just it?

Comment: If `nvme1n1` is not defective or bad, you just need to add back the partitions to the RAIDs.  `mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/nvme1n1p`, `mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --add /dev/nvme1n1p2` and `mdadm --manage /dev/md2 --add /dev/nvme1n1p3`.  The first two (md0 and md1) should add in the partitions quickly, but the md2 should take a while to add back.

Comment: I restarted the machine and it failed to boot so I did execute this command once again, recovered files, went with a fresh setup and everything works fine, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would first want to check to see if your raid device name has changed. An easy way to check that is:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

The most likely thing is that your device name has changed. The next thing to do is to check if you have an mdadm.conf. Typically that lives in /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf. If you have something there, paste the results and we can continue to assist.

---

**Update**:

```
mdadm --examine /dev/nvme0n1p3
```

Should show that your partition is associated with a RAID array. You can try other device members as well. The result you are looking for is that it should show up as being a RAID array and it should show your device information. So long as that is good, try this:

```
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

This just has mdadm look through your existing disks and try to remount the raid arrays. You appear to have a correctly configured mdadm.conf so that may just magically work. If not,

```
mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md2 /dev/nvme{0,1,2,3}n1p3
```

Should direct mdadm to try to use the devices listed to reconstruct your raid array.

Lastly, you are missing a raid member from all your devices, so you probably want to check why that is once you have completed this task.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer I appreciate it, I added more information regarding to your mentions.

Comment: @GuvenDegirmenci Updated answer

Comment: I am waiting for resync to complete, thanks for the update, I issued a similar command like this mdadm assemble force. I will let you know when it is complete.

Comment: Alright the resync is done, I added the status of drive to the post, I can access the files but I am not sure if I need to do anything before I reboot the machine.

Comment: @GuvenDegirmenci Sorry for the later reply; Your mdadm.conf file appears to be OK, so a reboot should result in the arrays coming back up. You did have one drive which was kicked out of the RAID, and I'd feel better about the reboot if your RAID arrays are clean. You can query the status with mdadm --detail /dev/md<device> or cat /proc/mdstat. You should also check dmesg for errors.

Comment: I restarted the machine and it failed to boot so I did execute this command once again, recovered files, went with a fresh setup and everything works fine, thanks for all the help.